# Search for objects within a Method and its References

Tags: java, search, reference

I want to search a class file for all `Methods` and `its references` for specific *Object types or Keyword*.

**For Example:**
Say I have class file called `myclassfile.java` which holds several methods as shown;

```
class myclassfile
{
  void doSomeFoo()
  {
   someReferenceClass.doFoo();
  }
  ..
}
```

And

```
class someReferenceClass
{
 static void doFoo()
 {
  for(int i=0; i <10; i++)
  {
   ..
  }
 }
```

As you can see `myclassfile` has a method which calls `someReferenceClass` and then invoke its `doFoo()` function. What I want to do, is create a program which peforms some kind of search against `myclassfile` to:

- Locate all methods which has a reference call to some method, that has `for-loop` within its routine.

And so for the example above, `myclassfile` will submit `doSomeFoo()` as a match.

Do anyone know how to go about this?!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to dig into either an AST or into byte code, depending on which type of rabbit hole you prefer. Working with an AST would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe there is a way to do this. Reflection will give you access to the methods and fields of a class but does not give access to the implementation.